# VS 2015 does not create the structure of the XML document comment

Tags: c#, xml

I am using Visual Studio 2015, working C# based project and trying to add XML document comment within the class.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends an email to welcome a new vendor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
```

I am using the traditional way by inserting three /// before the method access modifier but it still does not generate.

Any hint, suggestion how to figure it out this problem or should add manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normally Visual Studio 2015 creates the structure of XML document comment automatically by adding ***`3 ///`*** front of code and hitting ENTER button.

However in your case is not working so I suggest is better to add manually the XML document comment or you can use code snippet.

But you have to create code snippet as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Check Tools-> Options-> Text Editor-> C#-> Advanced-> Generate XML documentation comments for ///